# How to set permissions when uploading a file to Google Drive through the Javascript API?

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I'm currently using the Google Drive Javascript API to upload files to a user's Google Drive from their computer and simultaneously post a link to that Drive file.

This is working quite well, except that by default the file uploads with only the user who uploaded the file having permission to view it.

Therefore, what I would like to do is change the permission to "Anyone with a Link" to view it.

https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-js

This is the page that I used as a reference for the JavaScript required to upload the file to Google Drive. What would I need to change here in order to change the permission of the uploaded file?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge you can set the [visibility](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert) parameter to "DEFAULT" in the request something like this:

```
var request = gapi.client.request({
              'path': '/upload/drive/v2/files',
              'method': 'POST',
              'params': {'uploadType': 'multipart', 'visibility': 'DEFAULT'},
              'headers': {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary="' + boundary + '"'
              },
              'body': multipartRequestBody});
```

The other way would be inserting a file to Drive and then use [Permissions.insert()](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert) to insert permissions to that file by Id  and add a property in the request like 'type' to 'anyone'.

Hope that helps!